# $f'(x)$ to $f(x)$ is it possible without knowing the value of $f'(x)$ or $f(x)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

I don't know much math and i got stuck at a problem: I'm not sure if it possible how to do it.
I must use hermite interpolation for the following:

'Find the polynomial interpolating the function $f$ at the nodes $x_0=-1$ double $x_1=0$ double, $x_1=1$ double.'

I got to a step in the algorithm were I have to replace $f'(x)$, but I don't know how much that is since i don't know what is the value of $f'(x)$, and as I understand neither  do I know how much $f(x)$ is.

Q: Is it possible to replace $f'(x)$ somehow with $f(x)$?

Ps: hope I'm clear, or atleast I understood the problem.

Ps2: double on a node if i understood corectly it means it exists an $f(x)$ and an $f'(x)$

Comment: I don't exactly understand everything. But you can approximate a derivative such that $f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ when $h$ is a small value. What do you mean $x_0 = -1 \text{ double}$?

Comment: But what is the h? Does it stand for something?

Comment: Have you had calculus?

Comment: nop, not realy.